# Application to share screen, files, audio, etc

Tags: windows, osx, chat, screen-sharing

I'm looking for an application I can use to teach my classmates how to program.

Well, I give some classmates courses of programming, and I would like a software that lets me share my screen, audio talk, chat, and send multimedia. I have tried Skype to accomplish this, but it gets really buggy or disconnects some of my classmates, and really don't like it for teaching. I have found [oovoo](http://www.oovoo.com/), [join.me](https://www.join.me/), [netsupportmanager](http://www.netsupportmanager.com/index.asp), but NSM and join.me are paid or doesn't have all features I need. I'm using Mac and my classmates use Windows. Is there any software that I can use that meets my requirements?

Comment: Reading between the lines, the software you're after should be available at no costs (free as in "free beer")?

Comment: Please [edit] and rewrite your question: you are not at all looking for software to teach programming, you are looking for software to share your screen etc. I assume this is over the internet, and not in a private network in some class room setting? You should also address Izzy's question.

Comment: Teamviewer might be a solution for you (never used it to share screens between Mac and Windows, don't know how well this works).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [Google Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com/), I've used it a bunch for doing presentations for remote co-workers. It's got video, audio, chat and screen share, all pretty well integrated and over a browser. Video quality can occasionally get a bit bad, but it's available for free. I think there's a room size limit of 10 for the free tier, but don't quote me on that. Definitely worth trying out!